# Boost split function with multiple spaces

Tags: c++, boost, split

I am using boost to split a string

```
 boost::split(vectorStrSplitData, stdstrTxt, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_off);
```

when I use this string  where I add multiple spaces after the number I want the size of the vector containing the split string to increase.

```
std::string str = "Number         ";
```

The first vector element is what I expect, but there are no spaces. Expected output is:

```
{"Number", " ", " ", " " , " "}
```

I tried to query for space but got no result.

```
if (isspace(chr))
    std::cout << "Is Space";
```

Comment: What do you expect as result?
Check what `token_compress_on` does.

Comment: @SimonKraemer i did check what the token_compress_on does but i want  token_compress_off  , so that i can process for places where i have spaces

Comment: just that when i try to query for a space in the result i do not get that.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do honestly.
Maybe you can add some examples for input strings and the results you expect from the split. e.g. `split(" Number     ") => ["", "Number"]`

Comment: When you don't compress the delimiters it will extract nothing (empty string) between the consecutive ones.

Comment: If you want different behaviour you'll need to be more specific about how you want consecutive ones to be treated. E.g do you want your result to be `{"Number        "}` or `{"Number", " ", " ", " " " "}` or ... All of these are possible, but most likely you'll want to use a regex split / tokenizer.

Comment: you can't have the delimiter in the result using `boost::split`, the delimiter is only for splitting, not being part of the result. What you want is to use every second space as a delimiter or even separate words from one another and if there are more than 1 spaces between words then separate those spaces as well. Like ChrisD said - regex

Comment: @ChrisD i would want it to be {"Number", "  ", "  ", "  " , "  "}